# How to pass image data of AVCaptureSession captured image to another view controller?

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, avcapturesession, presentviewcontroller

I made a camera app using AVFoundation's AVCaptureSession and I wanted to pass the data of the captured image to another view controller.

This is the function where the capture os being handled:

```
func capturePhoto() {

    self.counter += 1

    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (buffer, error) in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let data = NSData(data: imageData!)
            // append the data to a global variable
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageData?.append(data)
            }
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)                
        })

    }

    if self.counter == self.count {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
        self.counter = 0
        self.shutterTimer.isHidden = true
        self.shutterTimer.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        // if the condition is met, then go to another vc with the image data  
        setupFrameAndSave()
    }

}
```

this is the function that handles the segue to another view controller with the image data:

```
func setupFrameAndSave() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "saveVC") as! SaveVC
    controller.imageData = self.imageData

    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Now, the problem is that the data that is being passed prints nil and placing the appending data to array inside DispatchQueue.main.async didn't do anything.

Comment: you should put `setupFrameAndSave()` in the callback of `captureStillImageAsynchronously `

Comment: I did, now setupFrameAndSave() is not being called anymore.

Comment: I need setupFrameAndSave() to run when if self.counter == self.count condition is met.

Comment: @RendellLasola `captureStillImageAsynchronously `is asynchronously calling. So you can't check the condition immediately after `captureStillImageAsynchronously` block because your condition is depend on callback result. So you should check that condition  in the callback of `captureStillImageAsynchronously`